# Oracle DB connection with Node.js Getting "Error: Schema User name is not Set! Try Set Environment Variable NODE_ORACLEDB_USER."

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have installed Node JS version 12, cloned node-oracle db from github.

I have also set OCI_LIB_DIR Path as mentioned in this [article](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127).

```
module.exports = {
  user          : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_USER || "hr",

  // Get the password from the environment variable
  // NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD.  The password could also be a hard coded
  // string (not recommended), or it could be prompted for.
  // Alternatively use External Authentication so that no password is
  // needed.
  password      : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD || abcd,

  // For information on connection strings see:
  // https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionstrings
  connectString : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING || "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl",

  // Setting externalAuth is optional.  It defaults to false.  See:
  // https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#extauth
  externalAuth  : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_EXTERNALAUTH ? true : false
};
```

I have created a basic connection in SQL developer, would it help.

I have installed npm in node-oracledb and also set the username, but when I try to run the command "npm test" , It gives me the error

```
Deeksha ~/Desktop/nodewithoracle/node-oracledb (master)
$ npm test

> oracledb@4.1.0 test C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb
> mocha --opts test/opts/mocha.opts

C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^

Error: Schema User name is not Set! Try Set Environment Variable NODE_ORACLEDB_USER.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\test\dbconfig.js:48:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\850044533\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\test\notes.js:32:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:330:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:327:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:804:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:207:16)
    at exports.runMocha (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:300:13)
    at Object.exports.handler (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:296:3)
    at Object.runCommand (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1087:28)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:63:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Deeksha\Desktop\nodewithoracle\node-oracledb\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: The first line of the linked installation article says it is out of date.  In particular you don't need `OCI_LIB_DIR` because it is no longer used by node-oracledb.  Follow the current documentation https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- set the credential environment variables to your DB credential values before you start Node.js.  The error message says `NODE_ORACLEDB_USER` is not set.

  Alternatively you can set the values directly in your `getConnection()` calls:

  `connection = await oracledb.getConnection({ user: 'hr', password: 'welcome', connectString: 'localhost/orcl' });`

  But be careful of hard coding passwords.
- Use a valid connection string; a JDBC connection string is not usable (Node.js is not JDBC).  See the node-oracledb doc [JDBC and Oracle SQL Developer Connection Strings](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#notjdbc) for how to determine what to use.  Based on what you posted, you should use just `localhost:1521/orcl`.

Save yourself some time, and read the node-oracledb [installation manual](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html), the [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html), and the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).